# How to Convert a JSON value to YAML value in Ballerina

Tags: json, yaml, file-conversion, ballerina

Is there a way to convert a JSON value to a YAML value in Ballerina?

Consider the following sample JSON file:

```json
{
    "user": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john@sample.com",
        "age": 20
    },
    "product": {
        "name": "Shoes",
        "price": 100
    }
}
```

The requirement is to first convert this into YAML format.

```yaml
user:
  name: John Doe
  email: john@sample.com
  age: 20
product:
  name: Shoes
  price: 100
```

Then encode this into `base64` encoding. Tried the [`ballerina/yaml` library](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/yaml/0.3.0), but seems like there is no direct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the [`ballerina/io`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/io/latest), [`ballerina/mime`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/mime/latest), and [`ballerina/yaml`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/yaml/latest) libraries. Following is an example code for doing this. Consider a `sample.json` file in the `resources` directory.

```ballerina
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/mime;
import ballerina/yaml;

public function main() returns error? {
    // Read the JSON file
    json jsonValue = check io:fileReadJson("resources/sample.json");

    // Convert the JSON value to the YAML value
    string yamlValue = check convertToYaml(jsonValue);

    // Encode the YAML string into base64 encoding
    string encodedString = check (check mime:base64Encode(yamlValue)).ensureType();

    io:println(encodedString);
}

function convertToYaml(json input) returns string|error {
    // Converting the JSON value into a YAML value.
    // This returns an array of YAML values.
    // The blockLevel indicates the maximum depth level for a block
    string[] yamlArray = check yaml:writeString(input, blockLevel = 10);

    // Finally, we join the array using a new line character to build the YAML string
    return string:'join("\n", ...yamlArray);
}
```

Read more about the `yaml:writeString()` function in the [YAML module API docs](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/yaml/0.4.0#writeString).